# @future(callout=true) AppExchange Package is Deprecated, Details: The AppExchange package has been deprecated and can no longer be installed

Tags: apex, trigger, callout, package-install

I'm experiencing an issue when trying to make an asynchronous HTTP call within an Apex Trigger using the @future(callout=true) annotation. The objective is to trigger a package installation via an HTTP request to Salesforce's Tooling API PackageInstallRequest endpoint.

The code works flawlessly without the @future annotation. However, as I need to invoke this method from an Apex Trigger, which necessitates using the @future annotation to make HTTP callouts, I encounter an error.

The error message I receive:

```
        "Id": "0Hf5h000001RcTVCA0",
        "Status": "ERROR",
        "Errors": {
          "errors": [
            {
              "message": "Package(0335j000000ttXG) AppExchange Package is Deprecated, Details: The AppExchange package has been deprecated and can no longer be installed.          Please try installing a newer version, or contact the package owner directly to resolve."
            }
          ]
        },
```

Here is the code call HTTP

```
public class PackageInstaller {
    public class PackageInstallerException extends Exception { }

    // Method to install a 2GP package using REST API
    @future (callout=true)
    public static void installPackage() {

        String instanceUrl = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm(); // Get Salesforce instance URL dynamically
        String endpoint = instanceUrl + '/services/data/v54.0/tooling/sobjects/PackageInstallRequest';


        // Get current user's session ID 0Hf5h000001RcTVCA0(access token)
        String accessToken = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        
        ManabieAllInOneVerion__c settings = ManabieAllInOneVerion__c.getInstance();
        String latestPackageVersion = settings != null ? settings.Version__c : '';
        
        
        if (latestPackageVersion == '') {
            throw new PackageInstallerException('No package version found in Custom Setting');
        }


        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        // Create the JSON payload
        String jsonPayload = '{' +
            '"SubscriberPackageVersionKey": "' + latestPackageVersion + '",' +
            '"NameConflictResolution": "Block",' + 
            '"SecurityType": "Full"' + 
        '}';
        req.setBody(jsonPayload);

        // Execute HTTP request
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

        // Handle response
        if (res.getStatusCode() >= 200 && res.getStatusCode() <= 299) {
            // Successful request, handle response here
            System.debug('Package installation request successful: ' + res.getBody());
        } else {
            // Error handling for failed request
            System.debug('Package installation request failed. Status code: ' + res.getStatusCode());
            System.debug('Error message: ' + res.getBody());
            System.debug('Full response: ' + res);
        }
    }

}
```

Any insights on why using @future(callout=true) for making HTTP callouts within an Apex Trigger might lead to this deprecation error? Suggestions on potential workarounds or approaches to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help and insights!

Comment: I cannot see that the error is related to the inclusion of `@future` and suggest it is coincidental. The suggestion is that the package version you have defined has been deprecated. BTW, using `@future` from a trigger is a broken recommendation. Read [this article](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) for an explanation as to why and see [this example code](https://github.com/sirephil/sf-async-callout) for a robust alternative.